# (Dimension theory)How can I derive this corollary from Theorem 5.4.7?

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

I’m reading this pdf on dimension theory in commutative algebra: https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~r-ash/ComAlg/ComAlg5.pdf

and having trouble in reading the proof of Corollary 5.4.8 which says I can immediately prove this corollary from the theorem above (i.e. Theorem 5.4.7), but I really can’t see how the author proved the corollary with the theorem.

First, in the proof, it says “replace $R$ by $R_P$ and $R/(a)$ by $(R_P)_Q$” but I don’t see why I can replace $R/(a)$ by $(R_P)_Q$ instead of $(R_P)/(a)$.

And also, secondly, I really can’t figure out how the author derived the formula $\text{ht} P -1$with the theorem.

Can anyone help me with this? Can anyone give me some more details? Thanks in advance.

$\textbf{My attempts}$

I could derive $\text{dim} R_P/(a)=\text{coht} (a)=\text{coht} Q$, $\text{ht} P/(a)=\text{dim} {R/(a)}_{P/(a)}$ and also $\text{coht} (a) = \text{coht} Q, \text{ht} (a) = \text{ht} Q$ direclty from the definitions but I don’t know this would complete the proof. Can I use the fact localization and quotient commute?

$\textbf{Theorem and corollary}$

Theorem 5.4.7 : Let $R$ be a Noetherian local ring with maximal ideal $m$ and let $a\in m$ be a non zero divisor. Then, $\text{dim} R/(a)=\text{dim} R-1$.

Corollary 5.4.8 : Let $a$ be a non zero divisor belonging to the prime ideal $P$ of the Noetherian ring $R$. Then $\text{ht} P/(a)=\text{ht} P-1$.

proof : In (5.4.7), replace $R$ by $R_P$ and $R/(a)$ by $(R_P)_Q$, where $Q$ is a minimal prime ideal over $(a)$.

Comment: It may be helpful to place the statement of Theorem 5.4.7 and Corollary 5.4.8, along with the proof of the corollary, in your question (in addition to the link to the document you already have).

Comment: Sure! I added it!